# QGIS to Web Categorized Symbol issues

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis2web

I am exporting my QGIS project with categorized information but for some unknown reasons, the layer only shows when you zoom in to a larger extent and not when you zoom out or zoom to the whole extent. Other non categorized layers works perfectly fine both symbols and text. I am using OpenLayers which I would like to stick to. The categorized symbols works fine with leaflet but I do not want to use reaflet for other reasons-reaflet also give text issues.

Comment: Which version of qgis2web are you using, and is your layer points? The most recent version (3.1.1) has a fix for OpenLayers points disappearing.

Comment: I am using 2.8, & it was the polygon shapefile I had an issue with. I managed to get it to work by filling in columns with no values, the points appears but somehow disappears as you zoom in & out but not that bad. I notice the plugin does not support well exporting data stored in PostGis, you have to export to .shp which works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed the reason why QGIS to web was not rendering the map was due to unspecified value within the attribute table. As soon as I fixed the attribute and have values in all columns, it works just fine